# How to install a specific version of a package with pip

Tags: gcc, centos, pip, yum, pyquery

I want to install [Pyquery 1.2.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery/1.2.4) version, but when I try

```
 pip install pyquery==1.2.4
```

I face with

```
  Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    creating tmp
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitXZJM6c.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitXZJM6c.o
    /tmp/xmlXPathInitXZJM6c.c:1:26: error: libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cmQUrb/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YFpKDF-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cmQUrb/lxml

    No matching distribution found for python-pyquery
```

I know it because my Python version (2.6), and I can't update it to 2.7 because of  yum

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may possibly be missing XML dependencies which your GCC compiler is spitting out at you, which can be installed with the following:

`yum install libxslt-devel` `libxml2-devel` `libxml2` `libxslt`

After installing each the development and release dependencies, try:

`pip install pyquery==1.2.4`

Which should successfully execute. You should be also able to update Python with the following method: **[here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/wiki/Installing-python-2.7-on-centos-6.3.-Follow-this-sequence-exactly-for-centos-machine-only)**. (Probably depends on your OS version.)

The above method explains:

> ```
> yum install -y centos-release-SCL 
> yum install -y python27
> ```
>
> Okay for centos 6.4 also On apu.0xdata.loc, after this install was done
>
> ```
> $ which python 
> /usr/local/bin/python
>
> $ python -V
> Python 2.7.3
>
> $ ls -ltr /usr/local/bin/pyth*
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jan 30  2013 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python2.7
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6162289 Sep  3 00:59 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1624 Sep  3 01:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
> ```
>
> So yum will use '/usr/bin/python' which is 2.6
>
> ```
> $ /usr/bin/python -V
> Python 2.6.6
> ```
>
> "python" will give you python 2.7.
>
> "python2.7" will give you python 2.7.
>
> "easy_install" and "easy_install-2.7" will easy install for python 2.7. While separate files, they both seem to install into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Comment: I am on centos and I try them with yum install but ** * updates: mirror.city.net.tr
No package install available.
No package libxml2-dev available.
No package libxslt1-dev available.
No package python-dev a**

Comment: @zhilevan Try running: `yum list | grep xml`, and see if the packages are there, with a different name.

Comment: @zhilevan They should be somewhat similar to: `libxml2-devel` and `libxslt-devel`.

Comment: @zhilevan All went well?

Comment: tnx for your answer, you answer help me to find my way, before this step I try to `yum install python-lxml` and try  your answer and everything work correctly, tnx

Comment: @zhilevan Great news! Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some OS related dependencies.

Try this:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
sudo apt install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

Or so:

```
sudo apt install python-pyquery
```

Comment: I am on centos and I try them with yum install but ** * updates: mirror.city.net.tr
No package install available.
No package libxml2-dev available.
No package libxslt1-dev available.
No package python-dev a**
my problem is because my python version,